# Post mortem debugging of the multi-thread scripts

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pdb

I am trying to debugging multi-thread script. Once the exception is
raised I want to:

1. report it to monitoring system (just print in following example)
2. stop whole script (including all other threads)
3. call post mortem debugger prompt in a perspective raised exception

I prepare pretty complicated example to show how I tried to solve it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import inspect
import traceback
import sys
import os
import time


def POST_PORTEM_DEBUGGER(type, value, tb):
    traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
    print
    if hasattr(sys, 'ps1') or not sys.stderr.isatty():
        import rpdb
        rpdb.pdb.pm()
    else:
        import pdb
        pdb.pm()

sys.excepthook = POST_PORTEM_DEBUGGER



class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.exception = None
        self.info = None
        self.the_calling_script_name = os.path.abspath(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename)

    def main(self):
        "Virtual method to be implemented by inherited worker"
        return self

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.main()
        except Exception as exception:
            self.exception = exception
            self.info = traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[-1]
            # because of bug http://bugs.python.org/issue1230540
            # I cannot use just "raise" under threading.Thread
            sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())

    def __del__(self):
        print 'MyThread via {} catch "{}: {}" in {}() from {}:{}: {}'.format(self.the_calling_script_name, type(self.exception).__name__, str(self.exception), self.info[2], os.path.basename(self.info[0]), self.info[1], self.info[3])




class Worker(MyThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def main(self):
        """ worker job """
        counter = 0
        while True:
            counter += 1
            print self
            time.sleep(1.0)
            if counter == 3:
                pass # print 1/0


def main():

    Worker().start()

    counter = 1
    while True:
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(1.0)
        if counter == 3:
            pass # print 1/0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The trick with

```
sys.excepthook = POST_PORTEM_DEBUGGER
```

works perfectly if no threads are involved. I found that in case of
multi-thread script I can use [rpdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpdb/0.1.3) for debuggig by calling:

```
import rpdb; rpdb.set_trace()
```

It works perfectly for defined breakpoint but I want to debug
multi-thread script post mortem (after the uncatched exception is
raised). When I try to use rpdb in the POST_PORTEM_DEBUGGER function
with multi-thread application I get following:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
    File "./demo.py", line 49, in run
        sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())
    File "./demo.py", line 22, in POST_PORTEM_DEBUGGER
        pdb.pm()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1270, in pm
        post_mortem(sys.last_traceback)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'last_traceback'
```

I looks like the

```
sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())
```

did not set up all what the `raise` command does.
I want the same behavior if the exception is raised in main() even
under started thread.

Answer (score 2):

*(I haven't tested my answer, but it seems to me that...)*

The call to `pdb.pm` (pm="post mortem") fails simply because there had been no "mortem" prior to it. I.e. the program is still running.

Looking at the `pdb` source code, you find the implementation of `pdb.pm`:

```
def pm():
    post_mortem(sys.last_traceback)
```

which makes me guess that what you actually want to do is call `pdb.post_mortem()` with no args. Looks like the default behavior does exactly what you need.

Some more source code (notice the `t = sys.exc_info()[2]` line):

```
def post_mortem(t=None):
    # handling the default
    if t is None:
        # sys.exc_info() returns (type, value, traceback) if an exception is
        # being handled, otherwise it returns None
        t = sys.exc_info()[2]
        if t is None:
            raise ValueError("A valid traceback must be passed if no "
                                               "exception is being handled")

    p = Pdb()
    p.reset()
    p.interaction(None, t)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But it ends with the ValeError exception (`t is None`). It looks like the call `sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())` does not setup what `raise` does.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @shx2's above, I now use the following pattern in the context of multithreading.

```py
import sys, pdb

try:
    ...  # logic that may fail
except exception as exc:
    pdb.post_mortem(exc.__traceback__)
```

Here is a more verbose alternative:

```py
import sys, pdb

try:
    ...  # logic that may fail
except exception as exc:
    if hasattr(sys, "last_traceback"):
        pdb.pm()
    else:
        pdb.post_mortem(exc.__traceback__)
```

Answer (score -1):

This can help:

```
import sys
from IPython.core import ultratb

sys.excepthook = ultratb.FormattedTB(mode='Verbose', color_scheme='Linux',
    call_pdb=True, ostream=sys.__stdout__)
```